# How do I fix this error when building Octave?

Tags: installation, make, octave, configure

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 Gnome edition. I'm trying to compile Octave 3.6.4 using the source. the `configure` went smooth without any errors but the make command returned me following errors:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [octave] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ankit/Softwares/octave-3.6.4/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ankit/Softwares/octave-3.6.4/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ankit/Softwares/octave-3.6.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

what more do I require to post to get the problem sorted?

Comment: Are you sure this is all error output you got? It looks like the linker is in trouble and you only included the final line of it: `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

Comment: actually there are thousands of line when i wrote make but these are the few last lines of the make command. Should I post the entire thing?

Comment: between thankyou @gertvdijk I did't knew how to format that.

Comment: You could post the entire error log on something like http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and link it in your question.

Comment: and this is the link for configure log file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jn6694tb8orfg13/config.log

Comment: The `make` output you posted shows a success, not the error you mentioned before. Are you still having issues? Or is it solved now?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5712859/ sorry this is the make output file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8989/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-gertvdijk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the problem sorted. The problem was with the fortran library not communicating with the g++ as I had F77 as the default fortran compiler. So I installed gfortran which helped in the liking and the make process completed successfully. This is the entire discussion [thread](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/make-returns-error-for-leaving-directory-td4653387.html) on the octave help page in case any one requires more help regarding this issue.